# Telegram client

Tags: python, telegram

I am testing telegram client build in python script. Below is my code

```
from telegram.client import Telegram

tg = Telegram(
    api_id=1111,
    api_hash='XXXXX',
    phone='+XXXXXXX',
    database_encryption_key='XXXXXX',
)
tg.login()

def new_message_handler(update):
    # we want to process only text messages
    message_content = update['message']['content'].get('text', {})
    message_text = message_content.get('text', '').lower()

    if message_text == 'ping':
        chat_id = update['message']['chat_id']
        print(f'Ping has been received from {chat_id}')
        tg.send_message(
            chat_id=chat_id,
            text='pong',
        )
    else:
        chat_id = update['message']['chat_id']
        print(f'Ping has been received from {chat_id}')
        tg.send_message(
            chat_id=chat_id,
            text='Okay.',
        )


tg.add_message_handler(new_message_handler)
tg.idle()
```

Above code runs an infinite loop or retries when I send a message other than pong to my telegram client. I was hoping it would just send "Okay." once. However when I edit the code to be as follows

```
from telegram.client import Telegram

tg = Telegram(
    api_id=1111,
    api_hash='XXXXX',
    phone='+XXXXXXX',
    database_encryption_key='XXXXXX',
)
tg.login()

def new_message_handler(update):
    # we want to process only text messages
    message_content = update['message']['content'].get('text', {})
    message_text = message_content.get('text', '').lower()

    if message_text == 'ping':
        chat_id = update['message']['chat_id']
        print(f'Ping has been received from {chat_id}')
        tg.send_message(
            chat_id=chat_id,
            text='pong',
        )


tg.add_message_handler(new_message_handler)
tg.idle()
```

It sends back "pong" only once and stays idle.

What am I doing wrong from the top code that causes it to go into an infinite loop or endless retrying even if I send a message only once to my telegram client?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're not accounting for the possibility of the bot processing its own messages.
Lets try to add a condition that checks whether the message was sent by the bot.

Here is an example, dont forget to replace `bot_user_id` variable.

```
from telegram.client import Telegram

tg = Telegram(
    api_id=1111,
    api_hash='XXXXX',
    phone='+XXXXXXX',
    database_encryption_key='XXXXXX',
)
tg.login()

bot_user_id = 'your_bot_user_id'

def new_message_handler(update):
    message_content = update['message']['content'].get('text', {})
    message_text = message_content.get('text', '').lower()
    sender_user_id = update['message']['sender_user_id']

    if sender_user_id == bot_user_id:
        return

    chat_id = update['message']['chat_id']
    if message_text == 'ping':
        tg.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text='pong')
    else:
        tg.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text='Okay.')

tg.add_message_handler(new_message_handler)
tg.idle()
```